# How do I create link to folders in Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.04

Is it possible to create link to folders (on the Desktop) in Ubuntu 19.04?

Answer (score 3):

Open the terminal
and write the command:

```
ln -s /path/directoryYouWanttoCreateLink ~/Desktop/name
```

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

In the Nautilus File manager hold the ALT key and drag the folders or files to your target location. Such as the Desktop Folder. Release the mouse button and choose "Make Link" A Link object is created for each item dragged over. They have a Link symbol on the objects icon so you can tell they are linked files or folders. (I did this in 20.10)