# How to merge two partitions on the same hard drive (one of which is the system file)?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, 20.04, gparted

I'm **very** new to Linux, coming from lifetime of Windows. And also, apparently, stupid because even though there are many questions similar to mine, I can't seem to find (or rather understand) solution.

Anyway, I have installed Linux (Ubuntu 20.04, dual boot) on 30 GB (as suggested by most installation guides out there) partition on an empty 500 GB SSD. However, the 30 GB ran out quickly, because everything is installed on the system file partition (to be honest I don't understand if I can just install new softwares on the other partitions).

In Windows, I used to install everything on C: drive and all my media and documents I kept on other drive (D:). I did this because I wanted to make a separation between my files and installed softwares, in the case I'll have to format windows.

Now, I wish to enlarge my Ubuntu system file (30 GB) partition. I resized the remaining ~450 GB partition and created a new 200GB partition:

[image: Gparted]

and I wish to merge the **unallocated** partition (186GB) and my Ubuntu partition (sdb5).

How do I do that? Is this possible?

Please remember that I read many posts before posting this, and still couldn't figure it out.

Am I too dumb for Linux?

Comment: No, you're not to dumb ;-) You have more than 12GB free space on your system drive. Should be good for many more apps to install. I would not do anything. With only 15GB used, this means that after Ubuntu installation + default programs you did not use a lot space yet.

Comment: Thanks for the very much needed consolation. I need to install a software (MATLAB) with size of ~ 15 GB.

Comment: Here you can find information: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483769/gparted-how-to-merge-unallocated-space-with-a-partition

Comment: So I can't allocate the 186 GB to the file system? Can I maybe move the entire Ubuntu installation to the 186 GB partition?

Comment: not so easy because you need to move partitions first as the unallocated space is preceding the partition. You could more easily create swap partition in the unallocated space (or use swapfile instead of swap partition), remove the old swap partition and merge with the space following sda5 (~20gb), would be easier and faster.

Comment: Quick question, now the swap partition precedes the ubuntu partition. is that ok? when right clicking the old swap partition i have "swapoff" option, while the new swap partition does not. will i have "swapon" in the new swap after i'll swap off the old one? sorry for the mess :)

Comment: did you mean creating swap from the  large unallocated partition (186GB) right?

Comment: It does not matter where the swap partition is located. You don't need that big of a swap. Usually the size of Ram + some extra GBs is enough, but there are lots of opinions on that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Every partition question is individual, and what's more: different options are possible, and the choice between these is to an important extent a matter of preference on how you want to organize.

A partition of 30GB for a linux system is plenty. You do run out of space because you also keep user data there. If you would move out all your user data, you would have plenty of space to install additional software.

**Option 1**. Your current sda5 system partition is at the end of the disk. To enlarge it, you would need to first move it to the front, after which you could expand it to the right. Moving a partition can be a very lengthy operation with quite some chance it will not succeed successfully. *I would not recommend to attempt this, even if it is possible in principle.*

**Option 2**. 30 GB for the system is (by far) enough if you keep all your user data out. So you can instead create a big data partition and move your data folders there. When you replace the current datafolders by symbolic links pointing to the real folders in the data drive, the system will, for daily use, work exactly as before.

Your current sda4 is a partition formatted in ntfs, the Windows file format. For use with linux, you shoudl use the ext4 format. Either keep it and create a new ext4 partition in the free space, or delete it and create one big ext4 partition in the free space.

Comment: Thanks! not sure what this means "When you replace the current datafolders by symbolic links pointing to the real folders in the data drive, the system will, for daily use, work exactly as before" could you please explain?

Comment: See here, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141186/how-do-i-create-link-to-folders-in-ubuntu-19-04, but you can also use the file manager: easiest is to go to Preferences then enable "show action to create symbolic links". Then, after moving your folders, you simply create links with the right-click menu. Then move the links  to your home folder and remove the "Link to " part from the names.